# How can I serialize multiple vectors into a single sequence with serde?

Tags: json, rust, serde, serde-json

Trying to serialize two different `Vec` fields into a single array in the JSON output. I can't figure out how to implement the `serialize()` method:

```rust
struct Base<'a> {
    workspace: Vec<Workspace<'a>>,
    methods: Vec<Request<'a>>,
    // other fields ...
}

impl Serialize for Base<'_> {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: serde::Serializer,
    {
        let mut state = serializer.serialize_struct("Base", 5)?;

        state.serialize_field("resources", &self.methods)?;
        state.serialize_field("resources", &self.workspace)?;
        // other fields ...

        state.end()
    }
}
```

I would like to serialize both `workspace` and `methods` fields together, however the last `"resources"` field overwrites the first one. I tried to workaround it using something like this, but it yields an error because `serializer` moves:

```rust
let mut resources = serializer.serialize_seq(Some(self.workspace.len() + self.methods.len()))?;

self.workspace.iter().for_each(|f| { resources.serialize_element(f); });
self.methods.iter().for_each(|f| { resources.serialize_element(f); });

resources.end();
```

So how would I tie these two together?

Comment: How would you like your output to look? Say e.g. you have a `Base { workspace: vec![0, 2], methods: vec![1, 3] }`, would you like a `"resources": [0,1,2,3]` or a `"resources": [[0,2], [1,3]]` or a `"resources": [{"workspace": 0, "methods": 1},{"workspace": 2, "methods": 3}]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest method is to transform your data into the Rust/serde equivalent of whatever JSON structure you want in the serialization function:

```rust
// in fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
// Declare whatever structs you need to make the required shape
#[derive(Serialize)]
struct WM {
    workspace: Workspace,
    method: Request,
}
state.serialize_field(
    "resources",
    &self
        .methods
        .iter()
        .zip(self.workspace.iter())
        .map(|(&method, &workspace)| WM { workspace, method })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>(),
)?;
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=960edc51ad6beefe994367df40e843f0)

However, this will create an extra allocation. If you're somehow super-keen on speed or memory usage, you could do without

```rust
state.serialize_field("resources", &ConcatSerializer(&self.workspace, &self.methods))?;
```

```rust
struct ConcatSerializer<'a>(&'a [Workspace], &'a [Request]);
impl<'a> Serialize for ConcatSerializer<'a> {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: serde::Serializer,
    {
        let mut state = serializer.serialize_seq(Some(self.0.len() + self.1.len()))?;
        for a in self.0 {
            state.serialize_element(a)?;
        }
        for b in self.1 {
            state.serialize_element(b)?;
        }
        state.end()
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=086800beed64dd05fd7269fe9954383d)